# TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'InspectOptions' as a type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im currently compiling a typescript file which has the following content in `index.ts`

```
export { default as Button } from './component/Button';
export type { Icon } from './component/Button';
```

I'm currently exporting the declaration for `Icon` as I'll reuse it in another file.

When compiling it via the lerna command `lerna run build`, i get this:

```
../../node_modules/@types/node/console.d.ts:35:37 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'InspectOptions' as a type.

35             dir(obj: any, options?: InspectOptions): void;
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/node/repl.d.ts:101:43 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'InspectOptions' as a type.

101     const writer: REPLWriter & { options: InspectOptions };
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

when I try to compile it via `tsc --project ./tsconfig.build.json`, I get this:

```
src/index.ts:2:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

2 export type { Icon } from './component/Button';
  ~~~~~~

src/index.ts:2:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2 export type { Icon } from './component/Button';
              ~

src/index.ts:2:27 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2 export type { Icon } from './component/Button';
```

the `tsconfig.build.json` is as follows:

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
}
```

I also saw this post on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27311 but am not sure how to apply the solution mentioned or if applicable for the above issue.

Any idea?

Minimal repo with replication of issue created on [Github](https://github.com/umarmw/magix)

Comment: Update to the latest TypeScript.

Comment: I'm currently using : "typescript": "^3.9.7",

Comment: Well, that error indicates that `tsc` doesn't understand the relatively new `export type` syntax. When you just run `tsc` from the command line, it doesn't use your project local version it uses a globally installed version of TypeScript.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I had Version 3.7.5 installed. I've installed the new version by running `npm install -g typescript@latest`. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've fixed the above issue by running `npm install -g typescript@latest`.

If you want to see the current typescript version installed on your system, run `tsc -v`

Thanks to Aluan for pointing this out.

If you still encounter this issue after the typescript update, you can consider to set `"skipLibCheck": true,` in the `tsconfig.json`